# Android network access control

Tags: android, security, android-ndk, firewall

I'm going to develop an android application which acts as a packet-filters or firewalls (like what ZoneAlarm does in windows which manages incoming/outgoing traffic of application).
**I want to know are there any API or methods to do so?** 

As long as I know, each app is run inside a sandbox which limits the application to limit activities of other apps, however I can assume my app can run with root access.